# How would you use Docker Swarm as a multiplatform Jenkins agent pool?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I've been successful in setting up a Dockerhost and using that host as an agent pool using the Docker plugin.

It works well, and does what I want it to do (spins up an agent on the host, runs the build, and destroys itself).

I would like to have a similar setup connecting Jenkins to a Docker Swarm with both Linux and Windows Dockerhosts inside the swarm.

Is that possible?  If so, what would be the best implementation of this?

Answer (score 1):

To use Docker Swarm with Jenkins:

1. Install the plugin [Docker Swarm Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-swarm-plugin) in Jenkins.
2. Configure the plugin to use the templates (docker images to use for building).
3. You can also adjust some other properties there, like CPU limits.